# How to implement a dict key generator that generates only keys with values of type list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, generator

I am trying to write a dictionary key generator that will generate a key iterator only if the value mapped by the key is of type list, using a recursion and a simple `isinstance` check (I've added some print statements for my own benefit as I can't seem to get this thing to run):

```
def list_key_generator(inputDict):
    for key in inputDict.keys():
        if (isinstance(inputDict[key], dict)): 
            print ("Entering dict: %s " % key)
            list_key_generator(inputDict[key])
        elif (isinstance(inputDict[key], list)):
            print ("Value is a list! key, value = %s, %s" % (key, inputDict[key]))
            yield key
```

I must be misunderstanding `yield` (not excluding something else) because exactly the same recursive function that prints out the keys, works perfectly:

```
def print_list_keys(inputDict):
    for key in inputDict.keys():
        if (isinstance(inputDict[key], list)):
            print ("Value is a list! key, value = %s, %s" % (key, inputDict[key]))
        elif (isinstance(inputDict[key], dict)): 
            print_list_keys(inputDict[key])
```

The entire example looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def print_list_keys(inputDict):
    for key in inputDict.keys():
        if (isinstance(inputDict[key], list)):
            print ("Value is a list! key, value = %s, %s" % (key, inputDict[key]))
        elif (isinstance(inputDict[key], dict)): 
            print_list_keys(inputDict[key])

def list_key_generator(inputDict):
    for key in inputDict.keys():
        if (isinstance(inputDict[key], dict)): 
            print ("Entering dict: %s " % key)
            list_key_generator(inputDict[key])
        elif (isinstance(inputDict[key], list)):
            print ("Value is a list! key, value = %s, %s" % (key, inputDict[key]))
            yield key

def main(): 

    inputDict = { "A" : { "x" : [0,1,2] , "y" : ["one", "two"] }, "B" : { "z" : ["one"] }, "C" : [9,8,7] } 

    print("Input dict : %s " % inputDict)

    # Print list keys  
    print("print_list_keys : BEGIN")
    print_list_keys(inputDict)
    print("print_list_keys : END")

    print("list_key_generator : BEGIN")
    # Print all keys in the dict, whose values are lists.
    for leafValue in list_key_generator(inputDict):
        print (leafValue)
    print("list_key_generator : END")

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

I'm using Python 3.4.1 , and here is the output:

```
Input dict : {'A': {'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': ['one', 'two']}, 'C': [9, 8, 7], 'B': {'z': ['one']}} 
print_list_keys : BEGIN
Value is a list! key, value = x, [0, 1, 2]
Value is a list! key, value = y, ['one', 'two']
Value is a list! key, value = C, [9, 8, 7]
Value is a list! key, value = z, ['one']
print_list_keys : END
list_key_generator : BEGIN
Entering dict: A 
Value is a list! key, value = C, [9, 8, 7]
C
Entering dict: B 
list_key_generator : END
```

Comment: Shouldn't you yield the returned value on the first branch of the if? value = list_key_generator(inputDict[key]) yield value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your generator recursively, you will not actually iterate over their results. Use `yield from` to delegate to recursive calls:

```
yield from list_key_generator(inputDict[key])
```

Other tips:

- Don't call `.keys()`; you can iterate over the keys by looping over the dictionary itself:

  ```
  for key in inputDict:
  ```
- In Python you don't need to put parentheses around the expression when testing with `if`:

  ```
  if isinstance(inputDict[key], dict):
  ```

You can use `dict.items()` to get both keys and values:

```
def list_key_generator(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict): 
            print("Entering dict:", key)
            yield from list_key_generator(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            print("Value is a list! key, value = {}, {}".format(key, value))
            yield key
```

Comment: Ha! cool! Thanks! actually, I also tried using `yield` without `from`, but this didn't work.

Comment: @tmaric: in that case you'd just yield the sub-generator without iterating. You'd have to do a `for sub in list_key_generator(inputDict[key]): yield sub`, which is what you'd have to do in earlier versions of Python without the `yield from` syntax.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips as well. I've noticed that yielding the result of the function call forces me to write `print(*leafValue)` in a version of the example, so I dropped that.